# Grafana difference between two datapoints

Tags: dashboard, grafana, difference, graphite, graphite-carbon

In a Grafana dashboard with several datapoints, how can I get the difference between the last value and the previouse one for the same metric?
Perhaps the tricky part is that the time between 2 datapoints for the same metric is not know.

so the desired result is the `<metric>.$current_value - <metric>.$previouse_value` for each point in the metricstring.

Edit:
The metrics are stored in graphite/Carbon DB.

thanks

Comment: Which data source are you using?

Comment: The metrics are stored in graphite/Carbon DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [derivative](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.derivative) function

> This is the opposite of the integral function. This is useful for taking a running total metric and calculating the delta between subsequent data points.
>
> This function does not normalize for periods of time, as a true derivative would. Instead see the perSecond() function to calculate a rate of change over time.

Together with the [keepLastValue](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.keepLastValue)

> Takes one metric or a wildcard seriesList, and optionally a limit to the number of ‘None’ values to skip over.
>
> Continues the line with the last received value when gaps (‘None’ values) appear in your data, rather than breaking your line.

Like this

```
derivative(keepLastValue(your_mteric))
```

A good example can be found here http://www.perehospital.cat/blog/graphite-getting-derivative-to-work-with-empty-data-points